# Use jQuery to switch between left and right text-alignment, depending on the language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input boxes and textareas that need to be toggled between left-alignment and right-alignment (depending on the user's language, the direction would be different). How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to dynamically align the text in the input field (either RTL or LTR) based on the language.

Comment: I have a Javascript for this. Would you like it or you just want jQuery?

Comment: @gurung-Yes, it is true, i want this.

Comment: Hey Kate, do you want this code just for English and Persian ? I think Vibhu edited your question in a wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have completely overhauled Mohammad's script but it's limited to its purpose: scanning if the first letter the user types in is Persian and changing the inputs direction according.

Here it is: [jsfiddle.net/uPH7N/4](http://jsfiddle.net/uPH7N/4/)

Comment: Nice work, Here a complete list of them for Arabic and Persian languages.
`this.characters = ['ا','أ','إ','آ','ء','ى','ب','پ','ت','ث','ج','ح','خ','چ','د','ذ','ر','ز','ژ','س','ش','ص','ض','ط','ظ','ع','غ','ف','ق','ك','ک','گ','ل','م','ن','ه','ة','و','ؤ','ي','ئ'];`

Answer (score 4):

As I don't know the key code for all Persian letters, I had to do it like this:

```
var str = $('#item').val();  //this is your text box
var firstChar = str.substr(0,1);
var characters = ['ا','ب','پ','ت','س','ج','چ','ح','خ','د','ذ','ر','ز','ژ','س','ش','ص','ض','ط','ظ','ع','غ','ف','ق','ک','گ','ل','م','ن','و','ه','ی'];
function checkPersian() {
    var result = false;
    for (i = 0 ; i<32 ; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == firstChar) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
if (checkPersian()) {
    $('#item').css('direction','rtl');
} else {
    $('#item').css('direction','ltr');
}
```

Comment: Pay attention that you have to change your direction just when the first letter typed in text box. checkPersian() will check it.

Comment: A hash would make for faster lookup. Even better would to find out if Persian characters have a contiguous set of codepoints in utf8. Then you could do a simple numeric test with charCodeAt().

Comment: Yes, you are right Jiggy. I mentioned to what you said in the first line of my answer. I don't have their key codes. So I had to do what you are seeing.

Comment: But I have this code in my project and it worked exactly for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir="auto"` attribute in modern browsers: **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/qHLXX/1/)**

```
<input type="text" dir="auto"><br>
```

Also you can do it by jQuery like this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/qHLXX/)

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val().charAt(0).charCodeAt(0) < 200 ? $(this).css('direction','ltr') : $(this).css('direction','rtl');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the elements' css with jquery (assuming the relevant inputs/textareas all have the class `textdirectionBoxes`):

```
$('.textdirectionBoxes').css('direction', 'rtl');
```

and

```
$('.textdirectionBoxes').css('direction', 'ltr');
```

Comment: How find out that it is typing in Persian or Latin word by user for rtl or ltr it?

Comment: So the question is not about how to change text direction but how to find out the user's language?

Comment: when user type value in input, it or is persian word or latin, if it was persian => RTL if it was latin => LTR. how is it?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```javascript
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    var language = navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language;
    if( jQuery.inArray( language, ['ar', 'he', 'ur'] ) != -1 )
        jQuery( 'input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea' ).css( 'direction', 'rtl' );
});
```

?

edit: fixed little code-bug

Comment: For me it works great when I set my browsers language to Arabic! (http://jsfiddle.net/uPH7N/2/ [edit] or even better http://jsfiddle.net/uPH7N/3/)

Comment: my browsers language!!!!!? i want get language when user typing word in input. no from browsers language. How is it?(i mean is persian(farsi) language no Arabic)

Comment: Please calm down, in your original post there is no hint to that("the user's language" normally is exactly that since a browser should take your language from the OS and most people with an English OS sure wants to write in English), please update according. Besides who said that only Arabic would be recognised (did you read the 5 JavaScript-Lines)? By the way, it would be new to me if the Persian language had its own language-code. I only know of Hebrew, Arabic and Urdu as RTL languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isUnicode(str) {
    return (str.charCodeAt(str.length-1) > 255) ? true : false;
}

$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(e) {
        $(this).css('direction',
            isUnicode($(this).val()) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.